# Swift - Collection View dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier EXC Bad Access Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, runtime-error

I'm working on an application where i have a `UICollectionView`. I created a custom Collection View Cell that contains a `UIImageView` and `UILabel`.
The following code causes `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) error on UICollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method.
This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class CategoryCell : UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet var categoryImageView : UIImageView?
@IBOutlet var categoryLabel : UILabel?

}

class CatalogCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet var categoriesCollectionView : UICollectionView?
var screenSize : CGRect?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenSize!.width/2-30  , height: screenSize!.width/2-30 )
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10

    self.categoriesCollectionView?.delegate = self
    self.categoriesCollectionView?.dataSource = self

    categoriesCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.categoriesCollectionView?.registerClass(CategoryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell")
    self.categoriesCollectionView?.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(categoriesCollectionView!)

 }

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {


}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = categoriesCollectionView!.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CategoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryCell

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor

    return cell
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-30, self.view.frame.size.width/2-30)
}


}
```

The po cell Output (Debugger):

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>   (code=1,address=0x0).
>       The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

The full stack trace :

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xdbea, 0x280abd6a UIKit`-[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:] + 274, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x280abd6a UIKit`-[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:] + 274
    frame #1: 0x28825da4 UIKit`-[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 312
    frame #2: 0x280abc38 UIKit`-[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 164
  * frame #3: 0x0010d428 SwiftTest`SwiftTest.CatalogCollectionViewController.collectionView (collectionView=0x1725c200, indexPath=0x16d9c560, self=0x16dbd260)(__ObjC.UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath : __ObjC.NSIndexPath) -> __ObjC.UICollectionViewCell + 296 at CatalogCollectionViewController.swift:50
    frame #4: 0x0010d850 SwiftTest`@objc SwiftTest.CatalogCollectionViewController.collectionView (SwiftTest.CatalogCollectionViewController)(__ObjC.UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath : __ObjC.NSIndexPath) -> __ObjC.UICollectionViewCell + 92 at CatalogCollectionViewController.swift:0
    frame #5: 0x2881fa74 UIKit`-[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:] + 408
    frame #6: 0x280abb82 UIKit`-[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 30
    frame #7: 0x280a9c6e UIKit`-[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 3726
    frame #8: 0x280a50aa UIKit`-[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 226
    frame #9: 0x28041a82 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 714
    frame #10: 0x2611dad4 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 128
    frame #11: 0x261191d0 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 352
    frame #12: 0x28057f9a UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 962
    frame #13: 0x28103aac UIKit`-[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 1168
    frame #14: 0x2810173e UIKit`-[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewController] + 250
    frame #15: 0x2811a55e UIKit`-[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 634
    frame #16: 0x2811a2ba UIKit`-[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] + 370
    frame #17: 0x2811a006 UIKit`-[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 758
    frame #18: 0x280806b8 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 204
    frame #19: 0x2807e9ec UIKit`+[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 324
    frame #20: 0x2810d060 UIKit`-[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 1732
    frame #21: 0x2810c996 UIKit`-[UINavigationTransitionView transition:toView:] + 26
    frame #22: 0x28103278 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 2548
    frame #23: 0x2810251a UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 834
    frame #24: 0x2810216c UIKit`-[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 52
    frame #25: 0x281020e6 UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 214
    frame #26: 0x28041a82 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 714
    frame #27: 0x2611dad4 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 128
    frame #28: 0x261191d0 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 352
    frame #29: 0x26119060 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
    frame #30: 0x26118580 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 368
    frame #31: 0x26118232 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 614
    frame #32: 0x261119ee QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 138
    frame #33: 0x23e70b20 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    frame #34: 0x23e6ee16 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 282
    frame #35: 0x23e6f254 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 972
    frame #36: 0x23dc1bb8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
    frame #37: 0x23dc19ac CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
    frame #38: 0x2503baf8 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 160
    frame #39: 0x280adfb4 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 144
    frame #40: 0x00108050 SwiftTest`main + 164 at AppDelegate.swift:12
```

Comment: Please check IBOutlet connection in UICollectionViewCell subclass.

Comment: IBOutlet connection is correct.

Comment: (a) and (b) checked. the ID is CategoryCell and base class is CategoryCell. @Rob

Comment: po categoriesCollectionView
▿ Optional(<UICollectionView: 0x161d8800; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x15670250>; layer = <CALayer: 0x15673a80>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x15631f80>)
  - Some : <UICollectionView: 0x161d8800; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x15670250>; layer = <CALayer: 0x15673a80>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x15631f80> @Rob

Comment: I've just updated my question. Please Check it and thanks @Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm inferring from your comments and the `@IBOutlet` references that you have a scene with collection view and prototype cell. If that's the case, you should not programmatically instantiate another collection view (the storyboard will instantiate one for you). Likewise, you should not manually register the cell class if you have a prototype cell with the appropriate storyboard id (the "identifier" for the "collection view reusable cell") and base class (because, otherwise, you can't use the cell `@IBOutlet` references).

It's hard to tell whether the crash is a result of the collection view you created programmatically or the one from the storyboard. For example, you programmatically set the `delegate` and `dataSource` to the collection view that the storyboard created, and then created another collection view which never had these delegates set). It's also possible that the problem stems from the fact that the storyboard's collection view called your delegate method to create a cell, but because you referenced your collection view outlet (which was now referencing another collection view) instead of the `collectionView` that was passed, it couldn't handle that.

But if you just eliminate the programmatic collection view and stick with the one from the storyboard, life is much easier.

When I did the following, it worked fine:

```
class CategoryCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var categoryImageView : UIImageView?
    @IBOutlet var categoryLabel : UILabel?

}

class CatalogCollectionViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoriesCollectionView : UICollectionView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.width/2-30  , height: screenSize.width/2-30 )
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10

        categoriesCollectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout

        categoriesCollectionView!.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)  // if you override these methods, call `super`

        // presumably you're doing something else here; if not, remove this whole method
    }

}

// If you want, you can define conformance of these protocols in separate extensions, to
// keep it perfectly clear which methods are for which protocol. If you'd rather keep this
// all in the base class definition, you can, though.

extension CatalogCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // I'd suggest using `collectionView` parameter in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`
    // rather than referencing some other outlet

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CategoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryCell

        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor

        cell.categoryImageView!.image = UIImage(named: "test")
        cell.categoryLabel!.text = "foo"

        return cell
    }

}

extension CatalogCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-30, self.view.frame.size.width/2-30)
    }

}
```

Note, I set the `delegate` and the `dataSource` of the collection view in Interface Builder (thus I didn't need to do it programmatically, above). But if you want, you can also set these programmatically. But just don't instantiate another collection view. The storyboard already created one for you.

Comment: Do note that forcable unwrapping can be dangerous and should be avoided.

Comment: Not true. Using forced unwrapping when an optional variable could be `nil` is dangerous. In this case, all uses of forced unwrapping above are cases where the variable couldn't be `nil`. And if it was `nil`, it's a programming bug and you want to discover the problem immediately. The problem with your example, where you did conditional binding, is that if the binding failed, you wouldn't know and you'd be staring at a blank collection view not knowing what the problem was. This is precisely the situation in which you _should_ use forced unwrapping.

Answer (score 2):

Its better to do this,

```
if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CategoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CategoryCell { .....(rest of your method code) }
```

This way you make sure you actually have a reusable cell before you try to run code on it. Also its better to use the methods collectionView instead of any outlet.